Vector form of kinematic equation for motion with constant deceleration
Here is the equation for finding the velocity in the case of constant acceleration:
$$\vec{v} = \vec{v_0} + \vec{a}t$$
Hence by integrating this equation with respect to t, we obtain position equation:
$$\vec{r} = \vec{r_0} + \vec{v_0}t + \dfrac{1}{2}\vec{a}t^2$$
All of these vectors point in the same direction and magnitude can be found this way:
$$r = r_0 + v_0t + \dfrac{1}{2}at^2$$
However, how would these equations look like in the case of deceleration? This sounds very basic, but I couldn't found any information about that case online, hence I am asking.

Can you explain precisely what you mean by "deceleration"? Are we meant to assume motion along a straight line?

By deceleration, I mean acceleration in the opposite direction of x-axis. It could be assumed that it’s along straight line. The way I would write this equation (but I am not 100% sure if it’s correct): $$\vec{r} = \vec{r_0} + \vec{v_0}t - \dfrac{1}{2} \vec{a}t^2$$

"All of these vectors point in the same direction..." You are asserting this, but it is not necessarily true. Are you trying to say "IF all of these vectors point in the same direction..."?

for deceleration  $~a\mapsto -a$

In everyday language, we use "acceleration" to mean increasing speed, but this is not how the word is used in physics. In physics, any change in the velocity is an acceleration. More precisely, the acceleration is the rate of change of the velocity vector
\begin{align}
\vec{a} = \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}
\end{align}
The acceleration describes not only how the speed is changing—whether an object is speeding up or slowing down—but also how the direction of the velocity is changing. In fact, an object can be accelerating even if its speed is not changing if the direction of its motion is changing.
Now, if an object is moving along a straight line, then it will only have an acceleration if its speed is changing. However, even in this case I would suggest avoiding the association of "acceleration" with speeding up and "deceleration" with slowing down. In fact, I would go even further and suggest jettisoning the word "deceleration" from your vocabulary entirely (at least in the context of physics).
With that out of the way, let me actually answer your question. Let's assume we are looking at motion along a straight line. An object with a constant acceleration $\vec{a}$ could either be speeding up or slowing down, depending on how the directions of the velocity and acceleration are related. However, the formula for the position of an object moving with constant acceleration
\begin{align}
\vec{r}(t) = \vec{r}_0 + \vec{v}_0 t + \frac{1}{2}\vec{a}t^2
\end{align}
is the same in both cases. The only difference between the cases is whether the acceleration $\vec{a}$ and velocity $\vec{v}(t) = \vec{v}_0 + \vec{a}t$ point in the same direction (speeding up) or opposite directions (slowing down). So the answer to your question is: the equation looks exactly the same!
Here is an explicit example. Take $\vec{r}_0 = \vec{0}$, $\vec{v}_0 = 2\,\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}\, \hat{x}$, and $\vec{a} = - 1\, \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2\,\hat{x}$. The velocity is
\begin{align}
\vec{v}(t) = \left[2\,\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s} - \left(1\, \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2\right) t\right]\,\hat{x}
\end{align}
Between $t=0$ and $t=2\,\mathrm{s}$, the velocity points in the positive $x$ direction, and since $\vec{a}$ points in the negative $x$ direction, the object is slowing down up. At $t=2\,\mathrm{s}$, the object comes to rest, and from that point on it moves in the $-x$ direction while speeding up.
Finally, let me note that your formula for the magnitude of the position (i.e., the distance from the origin) is incorrect. Instead, the magnitude of $\vec{r}$ is
\begin{align}
r = \sqrt{\vec{r}\cdot \vec{r}}
\end{align}
where $\cdot$ denotes the dot product (also called the scalar product). Let me write this out explicitly in the case where $\vec{r}_0 = \vec{0}$. It is
\begin{align}
r = \sqrt{v_0^2 t^2 + \frac{1}{4}a^2 t^4 + (\vec{v}_0 \cdot \vec{a}) t^3}
\end{align}
For example, with the values of $\vec{v}_0$ and $\vec{a}$ I used above, we have
\begin{align}
r = \sqrt{(2\, \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s})^2 t^2 + \frac{1}{4}(1\, \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2)^2 t^4 - (2\, \mathrm{m}^2/\mathrm{s}^3) t^3}
\end{align}

Deceleration is the exact same. Since acceleration is a vector, deceleration is simply acceleration in the opposite direction of velocity. For example, if we had $v_0 = 1$, $a = -1$, and $r_0 = 0$, the position after one second would be $0 + 1\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot - 1 \cdot 1^2 = 1 - \frac{1}{2}=  \frac{1}{2}$. In this case there would be deceleration.
A gap in your logic is that you cannot turn the vectors into scalars. The vectors may point in opposite directions, which is deceleration, in which you do not have $r = r_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2} a t^2$, you must use vectors.

Magnitude cannot be negative. $a = -1$ simply makes no sense. Direction can be applied only to components so it perfectly makes sense to say $v_x = 1 m/s$ which is sometimes written $v = 1m/s$ when x-component is the only component of a vector
